# Cakephp3 ORM ID as Key multi-dimentional

Tags: sql, cakephp, orm, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to get the following output from a CakePHP3 Table ORM object:

```
array(
       [primarykey] => array (
                                 'name' => 'users name',
                                 'created_by' => 'created by data'
                             ) 
     )
```

I have tried using:

```
$users->find('list',    [
                            'keyField' => 'id',
                            'valueField' => ['name', 'created_by']
                        ])
            ->where(['is_active' => 1])
            ->toArray();
```

However this just concatenates the name and created_by columns into a string separated by ';'. Example:

> [1]=> "users name;created by data"

How do I do this without manually parsing the data when I obtain it?

I have looked at http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs but can't see an example other than a list which is single dimensional.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that using the `list` finder for this is simply the wrong approach. While you could get it to return what you are looking for, I'd call that kinda hackish, as you are totally changing what a list finder is originally intended to return.

So, ditch the `list` finder, disable hydration, and use for example the collections `indexBy` method (query objects are collections)

```
$users
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', 'created_by'])
    ->where(['is_active' => 1])
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->indexBy('id')
    ->toArray();
```

This would return something like

```
[
    pk => [
        'pk' => pk,
        'name' => 'name',
        'created_by' => 'created_by'
    ]
    // ...
]
```

If you don't want to have the primary key field in the results, use a mapper to remove it

```
$users
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', 'created_by'])
    ->where(['is_active' => 1])
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->indexBy('id')
    ->map(
        function ($row) {
            unset($row['id']);
            return $row;
        }
    )
    ->toArray();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Queries Are Collection Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Collection::indexBy()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::indexBy)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Collection::map()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::map)**

Comment: That is great thank you, exactly what I am looking for. It is a shame I need to map the results in order to remove the ID as I suspect this will be a performance hit when returning larger result sets. I will need to experiment with either providing the ID within the result set again or mapping to remove it in terms of performance vs returning larger data sets.

Giving the ID twice (both as the key and in the value) is fine but feels like a waste but does allow for consistent data access while allowing records to be access directly from the array key easily if necessary.

Thanks again.